# updating setImage to work with IOS7

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7

I had this bit of code in a program that utilized a split UIView, now after you clicked the first option, you were taken to a new leftviewcontroller with about 10 options. When you selected one of those 10, you were presented with new options on the left and a picture in the right view controller.

That worked in IOS5, how ever im trying to port my program too IOS7 and however everything works but i dont get the picture on the right that i am accustomed too. 
Here is the code

```
if ([receivedRainObject isEqualToString:@"TEST"]) {
    self.lblSelWhale.text=@"SHOW UP;
    [self.label2 removeFromSuperview];
    NSLog(receivedRainObject);
 //   [self.view addSubview:self.lblSelWhale];
    [self.view setNeedsDisplay];
   // CGRectMake(<#CGFloat x#>, <#CGFloat y#>, <#CGFloat width#>, <#CGFloat height#>)

    UIImage *image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"bowheadtree.tif"];
    [imgClassification setImage:image];
   //  imgClassification.frame=CGRectMake(0, 80, 700, 500);
      imgClassification.frame=CGRectMake(50, 100, 600, 400);
    [self.view addSubview:self.imgClassification];
   imgClassification.frame=CGRectMake(50, 100, 600, 400);
}
```

I should note that the Nslog returns "TEST" just fine, but the picture doesnt show. any help to figure this out would be appreciated. 
Thanks

Comment: add some more NSLog to ensure that `imgClassification` and `image` are not nil...

Comment: @sergio imageview and image gives me 2013-10-07 12:06:04.949 Ocean[891:a0b] <UIImageView: 0xb1e45e0; frame = (50 50; 600 450); opaque = NO; userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0xb1e45a0>>
2013-10-07 12:06:04.951 Ocean[891:a0b] <UIImage: 0xb590b90>